# SVM training of HOG descriptor results (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction

I wish to classify cars by extracting hog features of positive and negative training samples. The problem is that I'm not sure what to do with the HOG features I acquired from each image in order to "convert" them into trainable data vectors.

**Edit:** Thanks, that clears out some things.
I was already trying to concatenate the matrix as Bentoy13 suggested (thanks) but was unsure about what dimension to concatenate. 
I just have one last question, using this method means I have to re-scale all my training images to the same size. So I was wondering if that will still enable reliable classification. If it doesn't, how can I overcome this problem?

For others who may have questions about the process of extracting hog features, I just found this [tutorial](http://chrisjmccormick.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/) which is very helpful in understanding the HOG descriptor and its uses.

Comment: Build simply a vector concatenating all histograms of a block (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients#Block_normalization))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `reshape(h,[],1);` or directly `h(:)` to vectorize the histograms inside the block. You may consider normalization for each vector as well.